# MYSQL - Retrieve Timestamps between dates

Tags: sql, mysql, datetime

All,

I have a MYSQL table with a column called timestamp. It is of `DATETIME` datatype and has values like "10/1/2009 3:25:08 PM', "10/1/2009 3:30:05 PM', "10/4/2009 3:40:01 PM', etc..

I want to write a SQL query to select all the values in the timestamp field occuring between two dates.. something like this:

```
select timestamp from tablename where timestamp >= userStartDate and timestamp <= userEndDate
```

The userInput dates will not have time portions. Can you please suggest the correct MySQL Query Syntax for this?
Thanks

Comment: By "it is of datetime property" do you mean that it has `DATETIME` datatype?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
SELECT timestamp
FROM   tablename
WHERE  timestamp >= userStartDate
       AND timestamp < userEndDate + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

This will select every record having date portion between `userStartDate` and `userEndDate`, provided that these fields have type of `DATE` (without time portion).

If the start and end dates come as strings, use `STR_TO_DATE` to convert from any given format:

```
SELECT timestamp
FROM   tablename
WHERE  timestamp >= STR_TO_DATE('01/11/2010', '%m/%d/%Y')
       AND timestamp < STR_TO_DATE('01/12/2010', '%m/%d/%Y') + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Comment: hmm.. Can userStartDate be in the format of "10/01/2009"?  (mm/dd/yyyy)

Answer (score 8):

```
SELECT timestamp
 FROM  myTable
 WHERE timestamp BETWEEN startDate AND endDate
```

> For best results when using `BETWEEN` with date or time values, you should use `CAST()` to explicitly convert the values to the desired data type. Examples: If you compare a `DATETIME` to two `DATE` values, convert the `DATE` values to `DATETIME` values. If you use a string constant such as `'2001-1-1'` in a comparison to a `DATE`, cast the string to a `DATE`.
>
> `-` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between

Comment: If both `startDate` and `endDate` are `Jan 11, 2010`, this will select only records with `timestamp = Jan 11, 2010 00:00:00`, not all records having `Jan 11` in the date portion.

Comment: You're right, Quassnoi. If that's possible with the users data, add 24 hours (as you did in your example). I had assumed the user would be using dateTime values within the query itself.

Answer (score 4):

The userInput dates will not have timestamps.  You can convert user input to timestamp with:

```
mysql> SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2007-11-30 10:30:19');
        -> 1196440219
```

Your query can become:

```
select timestamp from tablename 
where timestamp >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(userStartDate)
and timestamp <= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(userEndDate)
```

Answer (score 2):

If your looking to query an event between two timestamps, for a calendar or something where the start and end are stored as a timestamp you can use this

```
$qry = "SELECT * 
        FROM `table` 
        WHERE '$today_start' >= `event_start` 
            AND '$today_start' <= `event_end`";
```